# “Candaulismo” o “candaulesimo” (o altro)?

Tags: word-choice

Esiste una forma di voyeurismo alla rovescia in cui si prova piacere a mostrare nudo il proprio partner. In inglese prende nome da [re Candaule di Lidia](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/candaule/) ed è detta *candaulism*. Per l'italiano non trovo la forma corrispondente su alcun dizionario (né inglese-italiano né monolingue), mentre in rete trovo entrambe le forme “candaulismo” e “candaulesimo” (la seconda soprattutto sulla [Wikipedia italiana](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candaulesimo), di cui non mi fido in generale e tanto meno per questa voce, in cui sono più i “tag” di avvertimento del testo).

Conoscete qualche fonte affidabile (magari un dizionario medico o un sito attendibile, e non uno generico di consigli psicologici) su quale forma sia più corretta in italiano?

---

Per chiarire meglio: non mi interessano citazioni dalla wikipedia o da suoi cloni, non mi interessano citazioni da siti generici di psicologia (tutte queste cose le ho già trovate anch'io); conosco le differenze d'uso tra “-ismo” ed “-esimo”; non mi interessano più di tanto opinioni personali se non nei commenti. Vorrei solo sapere se in testi medici, articoli scientifici, saggi pubblicati, documenti ufficiali italiani è comparso finora il termine di cui parliamo.

Comment: Propendo per _candaulismo_. _Candaulesimo_ mi suona come una religione, un movimento o qualcosa del genere (andrebbe indagato il perché, ma il mio orecchio mi dice così)

Comment: @WalterTross: Sono d'accordo con te: se non troverò una fonte certa penso che nel libro che sto traducendo userò “candaulismo” (se ne parla solo en passant, a proposito del mito dell'anello di invisibilità di Gige).

Comment: Purtroppo, non ho niente in italiano, sembra che il vocabolo in spagnolo sia "candaulismo": http://alcmeon.com.ar/11/42/01_romi.htm , http://dspace.unl.edu.ec/jspui/bitstream/123456789/7430/1/Rafael%20Benito%20Arteaga%20Vera.pdf

Comment: Le due persone che hanno votato -1 potrebbero darmi un feedback, così capisco gli errori che commetto?

Comment: Anch'io vorrei sapere la ragione dei voti negativi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fondamenti di sessuologia](https://books.google.se/books?id=Vys0RazGiJsC&pg=PA338&dq=Candaulismo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bpHQVLLxGYToaPDNgsAJ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Candaulismo&f=false) di Salvatore Capodieci, Leonardo Boccadoro (Libreriauniversitaria ed., 2012), p.338:

> Triolismo, o triolagnia, o candaulismo, parafilia consistente nel provare piacere a osservare il/la propria partner impegnato/a in attività sessuali con un'altra persona

Si veda anche [Trattato moderno di psicopatologia della sessualità](https://books.google.se/books?id=TIPt9oWsrtkC&lpg=PA104&ots=bqXaRUvBG-&dq=triolagnia&pg=PA104#v=onepage&q=triolismo&f=falsesa=X&ei=15LQVJ7eFIXkaNy8gOAJ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=triolismo&f=false) di Fernando Liggio (Libreriauniversitaria ed., 2010), p. 104.

Comment: Ottimo, grazie!

Answer (score 2):

Cuckoldismo sembra essere un alternativa a candaulesimo/candaulismo. In effetti questi termini sembrano non essere ancora entrati in dizionari di medicina o psicologia.

[Candaulesimo](http://infatti-italiano.it/candaulesimo):

> - Il termine candaulesimo indica la pratica umana di tipo sessuale con la quale il soggetto prova soddisfacimento nell'osservare il partner durante l'atto sessuale con un'altra persona (Borneman, 1988). Il nome deriva da una vicenda narrata da Erodoto nelle sue Storie a proposito di Candaule, re di Lidia dell'VIII secolo a.C., e di sua moglie.
> - Nel linguaggio contemporaneo è frequente usare come sinonimo **l'anglicismo "cuckoldismo" dalla parola inglese "cuckold".**

[Cuckoldismo o candaulesimo](http://www.nienteansia.it/articoli-di-psicologia/atri-argomenti/calofilia-calofobia-oggetti-di-desiderio-oggetti-di-rappresentanza-%E2%80%93-candaulesimo-la-giustizia-di-afrodite/613/):

> - Esporre le nudità comporta un’occasione per rivelare ciò che abitualmente potrebbe essere solo intravisto o immaginato. Svelare una qualche parte del corpo, che siano le gambe, le spalle, il seno, equivale a puntare su quel fascino parziale, reso feticcio di sé, in base all’idea che ci si è fatti della propria capacità di attirare attenzione.
> - Chi espone con disinvoltura, in toto o in parte, questi aspetti non trascurabili del proprio essere “oggetto”, ricerca gli sguardi attenti, purché siano discreti, onde viverli con un buon dosaggio di gratificazione.
> - Una soddisfazione questa condivisibile dal partner che ha puntato sul valore di rappresentanza dell’oggetto. **Il “cuckoldismo” (da cuculo), o meglio candaulesimo (commistione di voyeurismo ed esibizionismo indiretto per identificazione con l’anima gemella)**,  in fondo, verrebbe esplicitato su questo tavolo da gioco. La rappresentanza predomina sul desiderio e l’oggetto viene spostato sul medesimo desiderio di chi viene sedotto (Ernest Borneman: “Lexicon der Liebe”,1984).

Comment: Grazie, ma queste non sono esattamente “fonti affidabili” nel senso in cui le chiedevo. La prima è un clone di it.wikipedia; e la seconda è proprio uno dei tanti siti di psicologia di imponderabile affidabilità.

Comment: @DaG - Prego!!!

Comment: Ho fatto le mie ricerche e ho confermato che questi termini non appaiono in 'fonti affidabili'. I termini comunque trovano riscontro in altre fonti, anche se meno affidabili. D'altro canto prima che un neologismo venga accettato dalla Treccani ci vuole un certo periodo di 'rodaggio' nell'uso comune. Penso comunque che siano termini usati da chi pratica o è' dentro questo tipo di attività' di carattere erotico.

Comment: Questa è una considerazione più interessante e utile, grazie. Pare che si possa concludere che non c'è una forma “ufficiale” di questa parola in italiano. (Ciò detto, perché -1 alla domanda?)

Answer (score 2):

*-ismo* e *-esimo* sono solo dei suffissi che hanno lo stesso identico scopo. Quello più antico e usato nella formazione di nuove parole è *-ismo*. Poche sono le eccezioni che usano *-esimo* (cristian-esimo, feudal-esimo).

Per cui, senza sapere cos'abbiano scelto medici-psicologi propenderei per la forma in *-ismo*.

Sembra esserci una sorta di regola per cui le parole che terminano in *-ano* e sono nei settori: filosofico, letterario, scientifico, artistico; preferiscono *-esimo*.

Una spiegazione approfondita sui suffissi la trovi [qui](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ITchAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=suffisso%20ismo%20esimo&source=bl&ots=k0Md_iu2kI&sig=BL61SbxruNBdqiHfkwI13TgRT-o&hl=it&sa=X&ei=uby1VNWMIoTLaIKUgeAC&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=suffisso%20ismo%20esimo&f=false).

Answer (score 2):

DaG, la tua domanda era "Vorrei solo sapere se in testi medici, articoli scientifici, saggi pubblicati, documenti ufficiali italiani è comparso finora il termine di cui parliamo".

Posso, invece, rispondere solo dal punto di vista di chi appartenga a comunità in cui ciò si pratica. In nessuna discussione scritta ho visto adoperare né il termine "candaulismo" né il termine "Triolagnia". Tutti, all'interno di queste comunità, utilizzano il termine inglese "cuckoldry" per indicare generalmente la pratica e "cuckold" o "cuckquean" per indicare rispettivamente l'uomo o la donna che induca volontariamente il proprio partner a vivere esperienze sessuali con altre persone